# Toggle week selected in react day picker

Tags: reactjs

I used React day picker for selected week.
My state updtes if choose new week.
I want deselect weeks in calendar, if i click to week.

Further, i get and post dates from server, so i want have check, that dates is selected. And if dates is selected, click to week must remove selected.

My code

```
    state = {
    selectedDays: [],
  };

  handleWeekClick = (weekNumber, days, e) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedDays: days,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedDays } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="SelectedWeekExample">
        <DayPicker
          selectedDays={selectedDays}
          showWeekNumbers
          showOutsideDays
          onDayMouseEnter={this.handleDayEnter}
          onDayMouseLeave={this.handleDayLeave}
          onWeekClick={this.handleWeekClick}
        />
```

In [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j2qje)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `handleWeekClick` to this:

```
handleWeekClick = (weekNumber, days, e) => {
    console.log(days);
    if (this.state.selectedDays.length) {
      this.setState({
        selectedDays: []
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        selectedDays: days
      });
    }
  };
```